# Geopy in Django: JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, django, simplejson, geopy

I have followed the tutorials in http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted
This works fine:

```
g = geocoders.Google(resource='maps')
```

I want to use json as the output format because I want to handle the results in javascript.

BUT everytime I use:

```
g = geocoders.Google(resource='maps', output_format='json')
```

I get the error below:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/business/view/13/
Django Version: 1.2.1
Python Version: 2.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'registration',
 'pley.business',
 'pley.review',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.webdesign']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\django\pley\..\pley\business\views.py" in business_view
  57.     for place, (lat, lng) in g.geocode(string_location,exactly_one=False):
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\geopy-0.94-py2.5.egg\geopy\geocoders\google.py" in geocode
  66.         return self.geocode_url(url, exactly_one)
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\geopy-0.94-py2.5.egg\geopy\geocoders\google.py" in geocode_url
  73.         return dispatch(page, exactly_one)
File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\geopy-0.94-py2.5.egg\geopy\geocoders\google.py" in parse_json
  123.         json = simplejson.loads(page)
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.1.1-py2.5-win32.egg\simplejson\__init__.py" in loads
  384.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.1.1-py2.5-win32.egg\simplejson\decoder.py" in decode
  402.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\simplejson-2.1.1-py2.5-win32.egg\simplejson\decoder.py" in raw_decode
  420.             raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /business/view/13/
Exception Value: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

Any advice / reply would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a bug: http://code.google.com/p/geopy/issues/detail?id=15

Changing: resource='maps' to resource='maps/geo' works

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the comments on the geopy page?

> Comment by gregor.horvath,  Sep 11,
>   2009
>
> Be aware that although there are
>   different output_format parameters for
>   the geocoders, the actual output
>   format of the geocode function is
>   always the same:
>
> location, (latttude, longitude)
>
> The output_format refers only to the
>   output from the geocoder service
>   (Google etc.), not the output of the
>   geocode function.